# Como posso subir arquivos no GIT com mais de 50MB de tamanho por commit?

Tags: html, git, github, commit

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei usar o Git Large File Storage mas acabou não funcionando.

Comment: Estou tendo que subir cada .html separadamente, mas muitos ainda sim ultrapassam o tamanho total de 1 commit por vez

Comment: Tenta usar o git-annex, é muito eficiente para arquivos grandres, lembrando que o GitHub, o tamanho máximo para arquivos é de 100mb.

Comment: Ia sugerir o git lfs. Por que exatamente não funcionou?

Comment: Apenas por curiosidade, esses html's tem 120MB por que motivo ?

Comment: São arquivos 3D do Blender convertidos pra HTML, em que eu utilizei um framework (Blend4Web) pra o usuário poder interagir com alguns elementos 3D e redirecionar ele pra outros HTML quando clica neles

Comment: @gmsantos Pelo q eu me lembro, 1º ele deu uma mensagem que estava excedendo o limite de tamanho (mesmo usando o lfs) e logo depois quando tentava dar push novamente, aparecia que o LFS estava desabilitado para esse repositório