# GitHub arquivos grandes ficam corrompidos

Tags: github

Quando tento enviar um arquivo maior que 100 MB, tudo ocorre bem no Git. Inclusive na minha pasta do GitHub o arquivo está normal e com o tamanho correto. Mas quando eu tento baixá-lo em zip para testar, o arquivo grande fica com 1 KB.

Quando importo para o gitDesktop os arquivos estão com 1 KB também (os maiores que 100 MB).

Já tentei com arquivo Rar mas quando baixo só diz que o arquivo está corrompido. Alguma solução?

Comment: Pode mandar o link do repositório por favor?

Comment: As vezes aqui tem algo que te interesse https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/432787/como-posso-subir-arquivos-no-git-com-mais-de-50mb-de-tamanho-por-commit

Comment: Ao meu ver o Git deveria ser para controlar a versão do software e como ele funciona e novas funcionalidades e organizar o trabalho entre equipes pequenas, médias e grandes ... Já os dados nem deveriam (com algumas exceções) ser "versionados", nem faz sentido isto, os dados devem fazer parte do ambiente usado e se precisa de um arquivo maior que 100MB é porque tem algo errado, a não ser que seja um outro software que recebe um "bind" da sua aplicação atual, mas ainda sim provavelmente tem alguma coisa má planejada no projeto em si.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Comment: Você não pontua suas perguntas, não tem interação com a galera, confira o [tour do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 6):

O Git não foi criado para ser usado para manipular grandes arquivos. Isso está sempre nas desvantagens dele quando se compara om outros softwares de controle de versão. Não quer dizer que não funcione, mas não é ideal.

Para o Git tem um mecanismo apropriado para lidar com essa necessidade que é o [Git Large File Storage (LFS)](https://git-lfs.github.com/) (agora foi comentado que está o usando, isso deveria estar na pergunta). Não resolverá para o Github, que é o que diz ter problema na pergunta.

Existe até uma [alternativa que a Microsoft criou](https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit) para poder trabalhar com o repositório do Windows, mas ela não está disponível para você usar no Github, pelo menos em contas normais e gratuitas.

E de fato o Github tem restrições para arquivos grandes conforme mostra o [*help*](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files) deles. [Esse tamanho em específico é proibido](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files), então neste caso a solução é não tentar fazer isso.

Podem existir outras opções, mas teria que saber o exato contexto, tudo o que pode ou não fazer.

Comment: Então, eu estava usando o git lfs.
Enviei todos arquivos (70mb) e deixei o de 100 mb para enviar com o git lfs.
Apesar de ele enviar ok o arquivo fica com 1 kb quando baixa.
E mesmo compactando em rar e enviando tudo continua a mesma coisa :/

Comment: Na sua pergunta disse que está usando o Github

Answer (score 1):

O GitHub tem uma limitação que não permite que arquivos com mais de 100 MB sejam versionados em seus repositórios.

A única maneira que o GitHub [oficialmente](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files) indica para versionar arquivos com mais de 100 MB é usando o ***Git Large File Storage*** (Git LFS).

Basicamente, o Git LFS permite que os commits apenas apontem para estes arquivos grandes, que ficarão armazenados fora do seu repositório GitHub, mantendo dentro do commit apenas um **apontamento** para o arquivo que ficará em outro local.

A instalação e uso é muito transparente. Todo repositório no GitHub já tem uma [conta gratuita](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage) para uso do Git LFS, que permite até [2 GB de armazenamento](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage) no plano gratuito.

Assim, após [instalar](https://git-lfs.github.com) o `git lfs` e fazer o [*track*](https://git-lfs.github.com) dos tipos de arquivo que deseja versionar no Git LFS:

```
git lfs track "*.war"
```

Todo `push` para o repositório do GitHub já enviará, automaticamente, o arquivo para o repositório do Git LFS:

```
git add app.war
git commit -m "Add war file"
git push origin master
```

O retorno do `push` mostrará algo parecido com isto:

```
Sending app.war
44.74 MB / 81.04 MB  55.21 % 14s
```

É possível [alterar o repositório](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.19/admin/installation/configuring-git-large-file-storage-to-use-a-third-party-server) usado pelo Git LFS caso não queira usar o repositório gratuito do GitHub.