# Problemas em fazer push para o Github

Tags: git, github

Olá, amigos!

Estou tentado fazer um push para o Github em um dos meus diretórios que, aliás, já fiz várias vezes. Só que agora está dando um erro que nunca vi antes:

- Meu comando:

```
git push Github Desenvolvimento
```

- Saída:

```
Counting objects: 203, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (197/197), done.
Writing objects: 100% (203/203), 472.59 MiB | 4.43 MiB/s, done.
Total 203 (delta 89), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (89/89), completed with 11 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 70d2c7976083db2df123f5b96d34bfc1
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Profnotas.zip is 311.76 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File build/main/PKG-00.pkg is 161.63 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To github.com:Israelmath/Profnotas.git
 ! [remote rejected] Desenvolvimento -> Desenvolvimento (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Israelmath/Profnotas.git'
```

Os problemas são:

- **Os arquivos são muito grandes** -- Mas o meu diretório inteiro tem pouco mais de 4 Mb;
- **pre-receive hook declined** -- Eu já tinha feito vários pushs e nunca deu problema..

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar? Agradeço demais qualquer comentário que me ajude!

OS:
Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Talvez seu repositório está enviando coisas desnecessárias é possível ver no log que existe mais de 400Mb pra ser enviado.  `472.59 MiB`. Tente revisar o que pode ter adicionado acidentalmente no git. A mensagem importante é que o arquivo build/main/PKG-00.pkg e possui 161.63 MB. O limite do GitHub é 100Mb

Comment: @Danizavtz coloque seu comentário como resposta para que ele possa escolher como resposta certa e fechar a pergunta caso resolva o problema dele.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/436352/112052

Answer (score -1):

Talvez seu repositório esteja enviando coisas desnecessárias é possível ver no log que existe mais de 400Mb pra ser enviado ao github. No total existem 472.59 MiB a serem enviados.

Tente revisar o que pode ter adicionado acidentalmente para ser verminado no git.

A mensagem importante é que o arquivo `build/main/PKG-00.pkg` e possui `161.63 MB`.

O limite do GitHub é 100Mb.

Todas as informações que eu escrevi aqui estão no log do GitHub que você disponibilizou.

Para remover um arquivo do git (apenas),  sem remover do seu sistema de arquivos, use o seguinte comando:

```
git rm --cached <nomearquivo>
```